# How to call resources name having variables

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Have a look at the code first

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-lab-cis01-${var.aue2a}-rgs" {
  ami           = "ami-0356d62c1d9705bdf"
  instance_type = "t3.small" #t3.small
  key_name = "${var.key_pair}"
}

output "lab-cis01" {
  value = ["Private IP = ${aws_instance.ec2-lab-cis01-${var.aue2a}-rgs.private_ip}"]
}
```

I have multiple servers, I want to use variables names in the names of resources. How can I do this? I can not also reference this ec2 name while creating route53 entries.

The error what VS Code is giving me is:
"expected "}" but found invalid sequence "$""

when I run the terraform init it gives me the following error

> Error loading /test/test.tf: Error reading config for output lab-cis01: parse error at 1:47: expected "}" but found invalid sequence "$"

Comment: You can't do this. Is there a reason you want to do this?

Comment: yes, sometimes i need to change the names because what aue2a means is us-east-2a availability zone. When i change this i need to go through all the files to change. i was thinking to create a variable for this purporse.

Comment: and do you know why exactly i can not do this ?

Comment: Terraform doesn't support interpolation in resource names or identifiers.

Comment: It feels like you're thinking about or structuring your Terraform code wrong but it's hard to tell from the limited context here. In general Terraform doesn't need to identify a resource by something like what availability zone is in because you shouldn't care at that level. Maybe take a look at some other existing Terraform code to get a feel for how people manage things living in different regions/availability zones.

Comment: you are right, resources names doesn't need these names